# How to go to different Views with with navigationDestination modifier for the NavigationStack for iOS 16?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I am trying to go to 2 differnt views from the NavigationStack by usgin differnt navigationDestination modifier, however I am always getting directed to the same destination. How to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Link1", value: "Link-1")
            NavigationLink("Link2", value: "Link-2")
                
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) {txtValue in Link1()}
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) {txtValue in Link2()}
        }
    }
}

struct NavTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavTest()
    }
}


struct Link1: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("You are in Link1 view")
    }
}

struct Link2: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("You are in Link2 view")
    }
}
```

I am aware that both my Navigation link are strings, so perhaps that's why I get redirected only to the first one, but how to modify the code so that it directs those 2 link in different views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.navigationDestination` just return a different View depending on the value of `txtValue`.

```
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { txtValue in
    if txtValue == "Link-1" {
        Link1()
    } else if txtValue ==  "Link-2" {
        Link2()
    }
}
```

However, rather than use `String`s, try using an enum with a case per View to get compile time checking:

```
enum Route {
    case link1, link2
}

struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Link1", value: Route.link1)
            NavigationLink("Link2", value: Route.link2)
                
                .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                    switch route {
                    case .link1:
                        Link1()
                    case .link2:
                        Link2()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```